# Css element directly next to another

Tags: php, css, position

Is there a way with css to put one element always next to another? I need it to be so that when a variable 'x' is passed through the url query string, an will change its position to be next to the element with the id of the value of 'x'. So for example, if you went to mywebsite.com/?x=foo, the element in question would display right next to (or below) the element with the ID "foo".

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

not purely with CSS.

you will need either encode the position in the HTML (by positioning it in the element tree, or applying a class or ID), or alter it with JavaScript.

there is nothing in CSS for saying something like "put this next to that"

Comment: +1, Although, it can be done via server side code :)